# Optimize my Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lump of Jquery which works fine I was just wondering if it could lose some weight as its quite a healthy chunk of code.

I'm sure it can be reduced to one function I am just not 100% sure how to do it.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tiles-tab").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $us = $(".square-tab, .tile-size-tab, .grout-tab");
    if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {} else if (!$this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.addClass("clicked-once");
      $this.addClass("active");
      $us.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $us.removeClass("active");
      $(".dropper").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(".square-tab").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $reset = $(".tiles-tab");
    var $us = $(".tiles-tab, .tile-size-tab, .grout-tab");
    if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $this.removeClass("active");
      $reset.addClass("clicked-once");
      $reset.addClass("active");
      $(".squarem").slideUp();
    } else if (!$this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.addClass("clicked-once");
      $this.addClass("active");
      $us.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $us.removeClass("active");
      $(".dropper").slideUp();
      $(".squarem").slideDown();
    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(".tile-size-tab").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $reset = $(".tiles-tab");
    var $us = $(".tiles-tab, .square-tab, .grout-tab");
    if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $this.removeClass("active");
      $reset.addClass("clicked-once");
      $reset.addClass("active");
      $(".tile-size").slideUp();
    } else if (!$this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.addClass("clicked-once");
      $this.addClass("active");
      $us.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $us.removeClass("active");
      $(".dropper").slideUp();
      $(".tile-size").slideDown();
    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(".grout-tab").click(function() {
    var $this = $(".grout-tab");
    var $reset = $(".tiles-tab");
    var $us = $(".tiles-tab, .tile-size-tab, .square-tab");
    if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $this.removeClass("active");
      $reset.addClass("clicked-once");
      $reset.addClass("active");
      $(".tiles-tabs").addClass("active");
      $(".mapei").slideUp();
    } else if (!$this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.addClass("clicked-once");
      $this.addClass("active");
      $us.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $us.removeClass("active");
      $(".dropper").slideUp();
      $(".mapei").slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you should move this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to  codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can do these:

1. Combine all the top level `$(function () {});` into one function.
2. Make all the `.addClass` and `.removeClass` on the same object, instead of doing again and again.
3. All the `.addClass` and `.removeClass` should have all the classes in it instead of calling them more than once.

For eg, the first block of code can be done this way:

```
$(function() {
  $(".tiles-tab").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $us = $(".square-tab, .tile-size-tab, .grout-tab");
    if (!$this.hasClass("clicked-once"))
      if (!$this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.addClass("clicked-once active");
      $us.removeClass("clicked-once active");
      $(".dropper").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```